# Adding one row of data to JTable from DB by id

Tags: java, phpmyadmin

I have a table i fill with data from my phpMyadmin database table, but I want to only have one row based on the id I write in a text field. I tried doing it as you can see in code, but I get a - java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from inputs where id ='11'' at line 1;
Any sugestions or solutions?
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S01To.png)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 0):

looks like there is something wrong with your sql statement. This exception will be throws if the syntax of your statement is wrong.
Please provide us the sql-statement you try to execute.

Comment: It's in the picture - select from inputs where id =?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Looks like you have to add an * after your select and a space after the =.
Statement should look like:
select * from inputs where id = ?